# Is there a way to run shell script which prompts for input values from Ansible playbook?

Tags: shell, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook which calls an existing shell script. Shell script when triggered standalone, prompts for some user input. I want the same functionality from Ansible playbook as well (call shell script with prompting from Ansible playbook).

I tried with shell/command/raw options in Ansible playbook (with no luck).

```
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false

   become: true
   become_user: oracle
   become_flags: 'content-ansible'

   pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: vars.yml
   tasks:
    - name: Do Create Users....
      shell: cd "{{v_dir}}" && yes | sh script.sh
```

Comment: Try [expect – Executes a command and responds to prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#expect-executes-a-command-and-responds-to-prompts).

Comment: EXPECT doesn;t seem to work for prompting values from Shell. What are the response values we enter for this ? 
My requirement is just to run shell script execute (with prompted values) ; Ansible is just a trigger point for me.

Comment: Please follow: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does not give you access to interactive commands.

You have to duplication the user interaction. First you have to ask for the input with [Prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) and second you have to feed the values to your interactive program with [expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html).

But this is not the Ansible way of life, because it is not reproducible. The main reason to use Ansible is to create idempotent jobs, which do everytime the same thing. If you ask for user input, the job depends an the input and this means it may do different things each time it is called.