# Ansible playbook file selection task

Tags: ansible, prompt

It's probably against best practice but using an Ansible playbook, is it possible to get a list of files from one task and then offer a user prompt to select one of the files to pass into a variable?

For example:

```
Choose file to select:
1. file1.txt
2. file2.txt
3. file3.txt
> 1
```

The playbook would theoretically pause for the user input and then pass the resulting file selection into a variable to use in a future task.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming it's not possible based on the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897507/is-there-a-way-to-run-shell-script-which-prompts-for-input-values-from-ansible-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html). For example, given the files

```bash
shell> tree files
files
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt

0 directories, 3 files
```

---

**Update**

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dir: files
    my_files: "{{ q('fileglob', dir ~ '/*')|map('basename') }}"
    selected_file: "{{ dir }}/{{ my_files[result.user_input|int - 1] }}"

  tasks:

    - pause:
        prompt: |-
          Choose file to select:
          {% for file in my_files %}
          {{ loop.index }} {{ dir }}/{{ file }}
          {% endfor %}
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: selected_file
```

gives (when selecting the 2nd file and typing '2<ENTER')

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [pause] ****
[pause]
Choose file to select:
1 files/file3.txt
2 files/file2.txt
3 files/file1.txt
:
2^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  selected_file: files/file2.txt

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

**Origin**

the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - find:
        path: files
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        my_files: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list|sort }}"
    - pause:
        prompt: |
          Choose file to select:
          {% for file in my_files %}
          {{ loop.index }} {{ file }}
          {% endfor %}
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "selected file: {{ my_files[result.user_input|int - 1] }}"
```

gives (when selecting the 2nd file and typing '2<ENTER')

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [find] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [pause] ****
[pause]
Choose file to select:
1 files/file1.txt
2 files/file2.txt
3 files/file3.txt
:
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "selected file: files/file2.txt"
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=4 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you for taking the time to reply.